# Error 788 when trying to connect to VPN on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vpn

When trying to connect to my workplace VPN from my home i get the error 788: "The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer could not negotiate compatible parameters with the remote computer. (Error 788)"

The weirdest things is that yesterday I was able to connect to that same VPN from my home without any problems... I am using Windows 7.

What does that error means and is there anything I can do to overcome it?

Thanks